# Adding to a class' variables with elements in an object

Tags: php, javascript, json, object

```
$class = new Class;
$foo = json_decode($_POST['array']);
```

In this highly contrived example, I have a class with its own functions and variables, blah blah.

I also just decoded a JSON string, so those values are now in`$foo`. How do I move the elements in `$foo` over to `$class`, so that:

`$foo->name` becomes `$class->name`?

Would be trivial if I knew what all the elements were, yes... except for the sake of being dynamic, let's say I want them all transferred over, and I don't know their names.

Comment: I just answered this before looking at your tags completely...be sure to tag the language/platform you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$vars = get_object_vars($foo);
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    $class->$key = $value;
}
```

You could also implement this in your class:

```
public function bindArray(array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

And then cast the object into an array:

```
$obj->bindArray( (array) $foo );
```

or add a method to do that too:

```
public function bindObject($data) {
     $this->bindArray( (array) $data );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to your class to load values from an object, and then use [`foreach`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the object's properties and add them to the class (you do not need to declare your class members before you initialize them):

```
class Class
{
  function load_values($arr)
  {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    { 
      $this->$key = $value;
    }
  }
}

$class = new Class;
$foo = json_decode($_POST['array']);
$class->load_values((array)$foo);
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course... foreach does $key => value as well... Cheers!

Comment: Well, if you don't declare them, they will be public...  Oh, and directly iterating over objects is not a great idea since they can implement the [`traversable`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface (at which point the code won't work as expected).  The cast (which you do in the code) is safe...

Comment: @ircmaxell true they will be public, but this is pretty unavoidable unless the JSON object will always contain the same keys, in which case they can be pre-declared. And fair point about `traversable`, I wasn't aware of it.